# Ubuntu 12.04 Server: permissions on /var/www for newly copied files

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, wordpress

I ran the following commands to set up ACL on the /var/www folder in my Ubuntu 12.04 Server:

```
sudo usermod -g www-data abe
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

I downloaded Wordpress using wget in my /var/www folder and unzipped the downloaded file:

```
cd /var/www
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
mv latest.zip wordpress.zip
unzip wordpress.zip
```

I created a new database and user in mysql and attempted to run the setup process through the web interface.

When I enter the configuration info in wordpress I run into the following error message:
**Sorry, but I can't write the wp-config.php file.**

When I run ls -la, I see that the files are owned by my user abe, but they are part of the group www-data.

Would I have to run the chmod command every time I copy new files to /var/www?

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

Comment: you can just give yourself permissions to the wordpress folder like so: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wordpress Just watch out. your files might be in a different path. Also, you could really just make this 666, and not 777 if you wanted to :)

Comment: 777 permissions would give everyone full access to the site material - not the most secure solution. 666 applied to a directory would prevent the user from entering the directory.

Answer (score 1):

just go to wordpress installation directory inside your www directory in terminal and give write permission to your web server which is running as www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

WP-config.php ins't saved in root I think.

Try doing this: `chgrp -r www-data wwww/` and then `chmod -r g+w www/` It will change group recursively, and then add Write permissions to Group, also recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you're not dealing with ACL here, just basic permissions and membership.

Here you can:

- Use the `www-data` account to perform tasks on `/var/www` (using `sudo -u www-data [command]` for example).
- Use `umask 002` which will creates directory with 775 and file with 664 permissions (if it is not the case already, otherwise you don't have any problem here).
- Use real ACLs (if enabled on your filesystem), for example `find /var/www -type d -exec setfacl -m d:g:www-data:rwX {} \;` which will create a default ACL (`d:`, so it will be inherited), recursively on directories (`find -type d`), with read-write access (`rw`) on all content and execute access (`X`) on directories, to the group (`g:`) `www-data`.
  You might also add this ACL on all already-created files : `setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwX /var/www`.

For the last two points, it's recommended that you know what you're doing, otherwise you could create a big mess in filesystem permissions if something goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

When you unzip files they come with their own permissions thus you need to edit permissions. But you could write a shell script which will do all processes for you.